# KeyError Even Though Key Exists

Tags: pandas, merge, keyerror

I am trying to merge two dataframes using pd.merge. I want to add the column 'Phone' from dataframe 2 if the company name exists in both dataframes. Every time I run my code, I get KeyError='Company' even though this is the column name I'm merging on.

Things I've tried:

```
pd.merge(northstar,julie['Phone'], on='Company')
northstar.merge(julie['Phone'], on 'Company')
pd.merge('Company','Title','First Name','Last Name','Address1','Address2','City','State','Zip','Mail Stop','Industry','Service1','Service2','Service3','Service4','P2','Fax or Ext.','Email','Secondary Contact','Secondary Email','Call Appt','Notes'],julie['Phone'],on='Company')
```

I get `KeyError='Company' everytime.`

## !/usr/bin/env python3

## Standard Libraries

```
import pandas as pd


northstar= pd.read_csv('/home/amypeiper/Downloads/northstar_dw_2018_q12019.csv')

                           Company                  Title  ...      Call Appt Notes
0                 24M TECHNOLOGIES          MECH ENGINEER  ...            NaN   NaN
1                   3D SYSTEMS INC          COMMODITY MGR  ...            NaN   NaN
2                               3M                    ENG  ...            NaN   NaN
3                        A & E INC              PROD ENGR  ...            NaN   NaN
4        A. W.  CHESTERTON COMPANY        PROCUREMENT MGR  ...            NaN   NaN
5                              ABB        SR MFG ENGINEER  ...            NaN   NaN
6              ABBOTT LABORATORIES       CALIBRATION ENGR  ...            NaN   NaN
7                ABBOTT MACHINE CO        BUYER/DRAFTSMAN  ...            NaN   NaN

julie= pd.read_csv('/home/amypeiper/Downloads/from_julie.csv')

[1457 rows x 24 columns]
                           company                  Title  ... Service4 Priority
0                 24M TECHNOLOGIES          MECH ENGINEER  ...       99      NaN
1                               3M                    ENG  ...       95      NaN
2                    4D DESIGN LLC        DESIGN ENGINEER  ...       37      NaN
3                        A & E INC              PROD ENGR  ...       41      NaN
4                              ABB        SR MFG ENGINEER  ...       52      NaN

northstar['Company'].isin(julie['Company']).value_counts()

result = pd.merge(northstar['Company','Title','First Name','Last Name','Address1',
                            'Address2','City','State','Zip','Mail Stop','Industry','Service1','Service2','Service3','Service4',
                            'P2','Fax or Ext.','Email','Secondary Contact','Secondary Email','Call Appt','Notes'],julie['Phone'],on='Company')
```

I'm expecting a data frame name result that has all of the columns from the northstar dataframe plus the 'Phone' column from the julie dataframe.
I keep getting this same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-e230d033a0e2>", line 8, in <module>
    northstar['Company'].isin(julie['Company']).value_counts()

  File "/home/amypeiper/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "/home/amypeiper/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Company'
```

Comment: `'Company'` in northstar versus `'company'` in julie. Keys are case sensitive. So just [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the column from one before you merge

Comment: I made this change, but I am still getting the same KeyError.

Comment: Not sure what change, but after you read it in, you should do `julie = julie.rename(columns={'company': 'Company'})`. There might also be white space padding so try to print `julie.columns` and see if there's extra spaces. If so try `julie.columns = julie.columns.str.strip()`, and do that for both.

Answer (score 0):

`juilie['Phone']` give you just the `Phone` column from `julie`. You need to include the `Company` column too:

```
pd.merge(northstar, julie[['Phone','Company']]), on='Company')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge on *Company* column, then **both** involved
DataFrames must have this column.

So the merge should be something like:

```
pd.merge(northstar['Company', ...], julie['Company', 'Phone'], on='Company',
    how='left')
```

Note that default merge mode (*how*) is *inner*. You have to change it,
otherwise the result will contain only companies present in both DataFrames.

If you want the result to contain all columns from *northstar*, you can omit
the column list for this DataFrame. On the other hand, I see in your code
that you included the column list (it looks like you wanted to omit
some existing columns).